# Getting Promise as return value inside FlatList React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

Showing Values using react-native `FlatList` like:

```
<FlatList 
          data={this.state.oldLocations}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          renderItem={({item,index}) =>
        <View key={index} style={styles.flatview}>
            <GoogleStaticMap
                latitude={item.latitude.toString()}
                longitude={item.longitude.toString()}
                zoom={13}
                size={{ width: 450 , height: 250 }}
                apiKey={'MY_API_KEY'}
            />

            <Text style={styles.name}>{item.id}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.email}>{item.latitude}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.email}>{item.longitude}</Text>
            {<Text style={styles.email}>{this.getAddress(item.latitude, item.longitude)})}</Text>}
          </View>

        }


        />
```

my Function `getAddress` inside FlatList returning promise. How can i show return values?
my Func:

```
getAddress(lat, lng){

 return Geocoder.geocodePosition({lat: lat, lng: lng}).then(res => {
      // res is an Array of geocoding object (see below)
      console.log(res);
      return res[0].formattedAddress;
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))


}
```

Comment: where do you want to call that function?

Comment: Inside `FlatList` to get address of lat, lng

Comment: What is the return value you're getting? What's currently being displayed?

Comment: you want to call it when the user, press one of the flatlist items?

Comment: Error: `Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`
no i don't want it to call on user click.

Comment: `console.log('res[0].formattedAddress') = '32/1, PECHS Block-6, Karachi, Pakistan.'`   // which is correct string.

Answer (score 3):

Async calls cannot be returned and rendered as part of your render. Instead, you need to perform the async loading outside of the render and then set the retrieved data in the state for rendering.

In your case, you will need to have a stateful component that you used for each item in your `FlatList`. This component will handle loading and displaying the result once it is loaded.

e.g.:

```
class MapListItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    address: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      item,
    } = this.props;

    this.getAddress(item.latitude, item.longitude);
  }

  getAddress = (lat, lng) => {
    Geocoder.geocodePosition({lat: lat, lng: lng}).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        address: res[0].formattedAddress,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // All your map/details - the other parts of your current renderItem
      ...
      <Text>{this.state.address}</Text>
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

And then your FlatList renderItem becomes:

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
   <MapListItem item={item} index={index} />
)}
```